# Looking for references of sobolev spaces involving time

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for references which introduce the the sobolev spaces involving time. What I have at the moment is only a short chapter from Evan's PDE-book. Is there any other similar literature but with more details about such spaces?